# Is there any way to generate database from Json or Xml?

Tags: sql, xml, json, database-design

I have a project and I have to design a MsSql database from Json file as dynamically. If its possible, could you give an code example please. If it isn't possible, could you say how  to query a Json file. İf you know how to create a database from Xml file as dinamically, I can convert Json file to Xml and I can realize your suggestion.

Comment: We need some more context. What is to be used for? Will this be a read-only database? Or are you going to have updates? Just one type of object/table or many?

Comment: Like @Thilo asked. And does the JSON data change 'a lot'? As in, if it's one type of JSON object or you have the schema for that or all JSON data you can receive, then you can create the DB in advance and load data to it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the data from the json tree, save the values needed in strings.
Form the queries to the respective tables in your DB, 
Use the values saved earlier to form sql queries and insert the data using jdbc.